# How do I post specific json data from php/mysql instead of all data

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, json

I have this code working pretty well except that it's going to post all of the results from php where I just want specific json_encoded data. Here's the PHP that pulls from my database.

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['charname'] = 'Egahtrac';

require_once ('mysqli_connect.php');

$q = "SELECT * FROM dps WHERE charname='" . $_SESSION['charname'] . "';";
$r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$dmg = $row['dmg'];
$curr_hp = $row['curr_hp'];
$tot_hp = $row['tot_hp'];
$attk_spd = $row['attk_spd'];

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

    if (isset($_POST['attack'])) {
        if ($curr_hp > 0) {
            $row['curr_hp'] = $row['curr_hp'] - $row['dmg'];

            $q = "UPDATE dps SET curr_hp='" . $row['curr_hp'] . "' WHERE charname='" . $_SESSION['charname'] . "';";
            $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);

            echo json_encode($row);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the jQuery

```
$('input#attack').on('click', function() {
    $.post('dpsloop2.php', { attack: true }, function(data) { $('span#curr_hp').text(data.dmg); });
});
// see here that i'm just trying to test if it works by echo'ing the dmg value to the curr_hp span to see if it changes.
$('#dpsform').submit( function() {
    return false;
});
```

I know this has something to do with the .text(data) part. But if I tried to do .text(data.curr_hp) it doesn't work. I've checked to see that the json array is echoing the proper format from php, so why can't I access that data.curr_hp from the JSON array?

Answer (score 0):

In your PHP you should only call `echo json_encode(something)` once. The JSON response has to be a single object or array; if you want to return multiple things, you need to put them in an array. So you should just do:

```
echo json_encode($curr_hp);
```

Then need to use the `dataType` argument to `$.post()` to tell it that the response is JSON. Then it will parse it for you.

```
$.post('dpsloop2.php', {attack: true }, function(data) {
    $('span#curr_hp').text(data);
}, 'json');
```

If you want to return the whole row, it should be:

```
echo json_encode($row);
```

and the JS should be something like:

```
$.post('dpsloop2.php', {attack: true }, function(data) {
    $('span#curr_hp').text(data.curr_hp);
    $('span#dmg').text(data.dmg);
}, 'json');
```

Comment: ok so say i want to pull all the data from the array out to jquery and i use json_encode($row) which is the array, can i use data.curr_hp to access only the curr_hp data?

Comment: Yes, you can do that instead. I was going to show that version, but then I saw the comment that said "I want it to echo only curr_hp".

Comment: In fact, if you're just echoing a single number or string, you don't even need JSON -- you really only need it for arrays and objects.

Comment: but say i have a php script that's outputting lots of data. i don't want it to output everything on the page. I can get the single string to work just fine. I'm having trouble getting an entire array working and outputting select data from the array. $row is an array created from mysql information.

Comment: If you `echo json_encode($row)`, then the JS should use `.text(data.curr_hp)` and it will just get that one piece of it. If you want to put different values in different places, just do it -- put `data.curr_hp` in one place, `data.tot_hp` somewhere else, and so on.

Comment: yes but here's the thing, it won't work lol. I've done that, it won't output the json data from the array when i use data.curr_hp, i even tested it and tried data.dmg too and it won't output that either. Even with your update to add 'json' at the end of my jquery function.

Comment: Please add to your question and show what you've tried. I can't tell you what you're doing wrong if I can't see it.

Comment: I think adding that 'json' at the end of the jquery function is not the correct format, cause when i just tried to output all of the data that wouldn't even work either. When i took that 'json' out, it worked again for all the data.

Comment: If you take it out, `data` is a string, and you can put that in the HTML. When you put it in, jQuery parses the JSON and makes `data` an object. You can't put that in the HTML, you have to access specific elements of it like `data.dmg`. You should be able to look at the object in the Javascript console, using `console.log(data)` or by setting a breakpoint and using the debugger to view it.

Comment: It's saying data isn't defined. So perhaps the string variation is working because having (data) in there is redundant for that purpose. How would i declare data as a variable with the $.post method?

Comment: You have to have a variable there, jQuery passes the data as an argument to the callback. With no `dataType` argument it passes the raw response string, with `json` it first calls `JSON.parse` and passes the result of that. If it's not working, there's a problem with the JSON. Make sure your script doesn't print anything other than the JSON. Check the Network tab of Developer Tools to see the whole response, and make sure it just contains the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Just got it to work, Here's the solution and it works perfectly. I had to declare data as a serialized array.

```
$('input#attack').on('click', function() {
var data = $(this).serialize();
$.post('dpsloop2.php', { attack: true }, function(data) { $('span#curr_hp').text(data.dmg); },"json");
});
```